# Logical AND with Swift Optional in IF statement

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have two properties. One of them is optional. these are defined below:

```
var advertiseCompleteBlock: (() -> ())!
var isAdvertiser: Bool = false;
```

Now, if I try to use this in my code like below, the compiler throws an error while building and fails with error code 254.

```
if (self.isAdvertiser && self.advertiseCompleteBlock) {
    self.advertiseCompleteBlock();
}
```

But if I change it like below, it works fine:

```
if (self.isAdvertiser && self.advertiseCompleteBlock) {
    if (self.advertiseCompleteBlock) {
         self.advertiseCompleteBlock();
    }
 }
```

Can anyone explain how are these two blocks of code different and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you compiler crashed. [file a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com/)

Comment: How about assigning an empty block to it (like `var advertiseCompleteBlock: (() -> ())! = ^{}`)

Answer (score -1):

If advertiseCompleteBlock is really optional it should probably be declared with a ? instead of ! which says that it will always exist.

I put your original code in a test file as a simple func and removed the references to self and it compiled fine. I don't know what the error 254 would be.

Is this code really what you want?

```
var advertiseCompleteBlock: (() -> ())?  --> really optional
var isAdvertiser: Bool = false;

if (isAdvertiser && advertiseCompleteBlock) {
    advertiseCompleteBlock!();    --> but now guaranteed
}
```

Comment: The code that you wrote with ? is valid but so is mine with ! The reason I used ! is because I don't want to unwrap it every time I use it, especially when I know that it would have a value always (just not at the time of initialization and hence I declared it an optional).

Answer (score -2):

Your block var is optional and is not initialized. So while unwrapping it will definitely be nil which compiler does not expect. That's the reason you get the compile errors.
   In the second case you are checking if the var is nil or not and then calling the block, so the compiler is happy in this case.

Comment: My block var is optional at the time of initialization but I do assign it a value later in the code. Anyways, if I understand correctly optionals return true if they contain any value and false otherwise, so in that case even if it does not have a value, it should return false in the first case as well instead of compiler error. Am I missing something?

Comment: optional are initialized with `nil` by default. it have nothing to do with compile error. and it is also check in the first version.